# How can you view total I/O Bytes Read/Written on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, performance-monitor, process-monitoring

How can you view total I/O Bytes Read/Written on Windows 10 per process? This is very easy on Windows 7 as you can see it in Task Manager if you enable those columns, but on Windows 10 task manager is very "dumbed down" and doesn't seem to have this function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Taskmanager from Windows 8/10 also supports this feature. Go to the `Details` tab, make a rightclick on the header and click "select columns" and activate the checkboxes at the IO options:

[image]

Now you see the numbers in the details tab.

Comment: Thanks - I'd missed the "Details" tab. I dont' really get why this isn't the same as the processes tab!

Comment: process tab is only a summary, details shows more data

Comment: I don't know how I missed the details tab. *d'oh*

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize Microsoft's own Windows Sysinternals [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see that data.

After you download and start Process Explorer, you can navigate to `View`, `Select Columns`, and then the `Process I/O` tab to select the ones you prefer.

[image: Process Explorer]

If you like the capabilities within Process Explorer (as many of us do), you can potentially use the `Options` menu and select the one that allows you to `Replace Task Manager`.

[image: Replace Task Manager]